# Android manipulate another Activity's UI Components from Main Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

How can I manipulate another Activity's XML file components (like EditText) from main Activity, in terms of `setEnabled()` etc. Do I need to instantiate a field `MySecondActivity` inside `MainActivity` class and manipulate it via methods i create in that second Activity?

I tried without doing that. I instantiated `EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)` in `onCreate()` method at Main Activity which is contained in the second Activity's xml, but that gives me null pointer exception.

Comment: An activity sees only their own view. Communication between activities is done via `startActivityForResult()` and `Intent`s.

Answer (score 0):

By android design, each Activity like different application, have to work independed as it can. You should send parameters as extras in intent and do your work it that activity.

But you can do it, for example linking activities by static field:

```
ActivityA {
    public static ActivityB instance = null;

    onClick() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
    } 
}

ActivityB {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityA.instance = this;
    }

}
```

After that you can access AcitivityB from ActivityA by "instalce", but again, this is not the right way!

Comment: I know about sending parameters as Extra, but i need to manipulate another activity's UI on demand. So when some condition happends in main activity, like internet dissconnnect, i want to disable some components in second activity, but when internet comes back i want to enable it. If you understand me...

Comment: For that, in android ususally they using broadcast, you send broadcast intent, and everywhere you need you catch it and process as you need.

Comment: Well actually I have client on main activity which connects on server in LAN. Should I pass that client as Extra to second activity and then add listeners there again, so I can manipulate what happends if it disconnects?

Comment: If you need to have stable TCP connection and access it everywhere, you can move it to Android Service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
This will be right solution from design point of view